# Install specific version of postgres using saltstack

Tags: postgresql, version, salt-stack

I'm wanting a really basic install of postgres, and the [postgres-formula/postgres](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/postgres-formula/tree/master/postgres) is just too crazy.  I just want to install postgres version 9.5.1 on a single minion.

Here's something I've tried, that I know doesn't work.

**/srv/salt/top.sls**

```
base:
  '*':
    - postgresql
```

**/srv/salt/postgresql/init.sls**

```
postgresql:
  pkg.installed:
      - version: 9.5.1
```

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pkg.html), this is the correct format.  I thought maybe I should have the 9.5.3 in a different format, but I can't find where to figure that out.

---

**Update 1**

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 on the minion, and the master.

The output of `apt-cache policy postgresql` is

```
postgresql:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 9.3+154ubuntu1
  Version table:
     9.3+154ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     9.3+154 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What OS do you use ? if centos print out the result of the following command: `yum --showduplicates list postgresql | expand` and if ubuntu: `apt-cache policy postgresql` because you need first to make sure that there is a version with the same number available on your system so salt can install it

Comment: Thanks, I'll update with that output.  Since it's only outputting 9.3, how would I get salt to install 9.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be done through salt using pkgrepo.managed.  The solution is below.

**init.sls**

```
 postgresql:
  pkgrepo.managed:
    - name: deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main
    - dist: trusty-pgdg
    - file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/psql.list
    - key_url: https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
    - require_in:
      - pkg: postgresql
  pkg.installed:
    - name: postgresql-9.5
    - refresh: True
  service:
    - running
```

I got this answer through a combination of the saltstack irc, and the [salt docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pkgrepo.html).

Comment: Problematic with CentOS 7 (and probably earlier versions). See my answer for your initial question when the minion is running on CentOS 7. I realize you updated the question to refer to ubuntu, but this seemed an appropriate place to answer the original question.

Answer (score 1):

In order to install Postgresql 9.5 using saltstack.

First make sure to to do as [this article](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-postgresql-95-on-ubuntu-12_04-15_10/) says in your ubuntu minion in order to make `postgresql 9.5` available to your system to install. or even you can write a `state` that automates the whole steps. adding the repository and installing `postgresql 9.5`

Comment: +1 for being correct on the logic, and helping.  Thanks for showing me how to find out which versions are available through apt-cache.  However, the way to do this through salt is listed in the answer I found on the saltstack irc.

Answer (score 1):

The answer offered by @trueCamelType does not appear to work with a CentOS 7 based minion. The following does work:

**init.sls**

```
install-postgresql96-repository:
  cmd.run:
    - name: rpm -U --force https://yum.postgresql.org/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm

install-postgresql96-server:
  cmd.run:
    - name: yum --disablerepo=postgresql -y install postgresql96-server

postgresql-first-run-init:
  cmd.run:
    - name: /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
    - unless: stat /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/postgresql.conf
    - runas: root

start-postgresql96-server:
  cmd.run:
    - name: systemctl start postgresql-9.6

enable-postgresql96-autostart:
  cmd.run:
    - name: systemctl enable postgresql-9.6
```

The `rpm` command is run with `--force` so that it can be repeated without issuing an 'error' indicating the package has already been installed. Makes the salt output prettier.

The `yum` command is run with `--disablerepo=postgresql` to prevent salt from trying to use an external repo.

It is procedural and not elegant but I found that futzing with `pkgrepo.managed` was more trouble than it was worth. That said would love to see a solution to installing postgresql on Centos 7 using 'pkgrepo.managed`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a really basic install of Postgres, just do the following to install 9.5 from https://www.postgresql.org/. Something like this works out-of-the-box.

```
$ sudo -s
$ cd /srv/salt/
$ git clone https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/postgres-formula.git postgres
$ ln -s /srv/salt/postgres/postgres /srv/salt/postgres
$ vi /srv/salt/top.sls && cat /srv/salt/top.sls 
#format: YAML

base:
  '*':
    - postgres

$ salt-call state.highstate --local
```

If you want to different behavior set pillar (i.e. in /srv/pillar/postgres.sls) accordingly first.

```
postgres:
  use_upstream_repo: True
  version: '9.6'
```